# how to upload files asynchronously (parallely ) using ruby net-sftp

Tags: ruby, multithreading, multiprocess, net-sftp

what is the best way to upload files parallely using sftp ?
using multithreading and multi-process is the only options ?
can we use any of the gems for that ?
I using ruby 1.8.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Net::SFTP's [`upload`](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-sftp/classes/Net/SFTP/Session.html#method-i-upload) method (without bang) operates asynchronously, i.e. in parallel.

From the [docs](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-sftp/classes/Net/SFTP/Operations/Upload.html):

> Or, if you have multiple uploads that you want to run in parallel, you
>   can employ the `wait` method of the returned object:
>
> ```
> uploads = %w(file1 file2 file3).map { |f|
>   sftp.upload(f, "remote/#{f}")
> }
> uploads.each { |u| u.wait }
> ```